# TiKZ and color filling with word spacing on multiple lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am attempting to make a figure in TikZ which I want to look like this:
[image: fig]

I have been able to come up with something close in TikZ, but I would really like to have the above figure instead of my solution.

```
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\tikzstyle{block3} = [rectangle, draw, fill=green!20,
text width=15em, text centered, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{block4} = [rectangle, draw, fill=purple!20,
text width=12em, text centered, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{block5} = [rectangle, draw, fill=red!20,
text width=9em, text centered, minimum height=4em]

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Place nodes
\node [block3,align=center,xshift=-30em] (as) {ASSETS \hline \\{\color{cyan}Cash + Accounts Receivable + Prepaid Insurance + Equipment + Truck}};
\node [draw=white] at (-7.5,0) (equal) {=};
\node [block4,align=center,right of=as,xshift=13em] (li) {LIABILITIES \hline\\{\color{purple}Bank Loan + Accounts Payable + Unearned Revenue}};
\node [draw=white] at (-2.3,0) (plus) {+};
\node [block5,align=center,right of=li,xshift=11em] (eq) {EQUITY \hline     \\{\color{red}Share Capital + Retained Earnings}};
% Draw edges
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: assets]

Comment: Always post **complete** code i.e. a small, compilable document. As posted, your code will not compile. A complete, small document is much more useful than mere fragments which leave helpers to guess you document class and the packages required to compile. You even leave potential helpers to add `\begin{document}... \end{document}` themselves!

Comment: Have you looked at `tcolorbox`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `tikz` for this. A simple `tabular` will do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{%       %% code stolen from egreg
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \strut#1\strut
  \end{tabular}%
}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\columncolor{cyan!20}\color{cyan}}c}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\columncolor{blue!10}\color{blue}}c}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\columncolor{red!10}\color{red}}c}
\begin{document}
\noindent
{\footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{CcBcR}
   ASSETS & $=$ & LIABILITIES & $+$ &  EQUITY \\\noalign{\vspace{-2pt}} \cmidrule[1pt]{1-1}\cmidrule[1pt]{3-3}\cmidrule[1pt]{5-5}\noalign{\vspace{-3pt}}
Cash $+$ \head{Accounts \\ Receivable} $+$ \head{Prepaid \\Insurance} $+$ Equipment $+$ Truck
 & $=$ &
 \head{Bank \\ Loan} $+$ \head{Accounts \\ Payable} $+$ \head{Unearned \\ Revenue}
 & $+$ &
 \head{Share \\ Capital} $+$ \head{Retained \\ Earnings}
  \end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to align the symbols at the top:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{%       %% code stolen from egreg
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \strut#1\strut
  \end{tabular}%
}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\columncolor{cyan!20}\color{cyan}}c}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\columncolor{blue!10}\color{blue}}c}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\columncolor{red!10}\color{red}}c}
\begin{document}
\noindent
{\footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{CcBcR}
   ASSETS & $=$ & LIABILITIES & $+$ &  EQUITY \\\noalign{\vspace{-2pt}} \cmidrule[1pt]{1-1}\cmidrule[1pt]{3-3}\cmidrule[1pt]{5-5}\noalign{\vspace{-3pt}}
\head{Cash \\} \head{$+$ \\} \head{Accounts \\ Receivable} \head{$+$ \\} \head{Prepaid \\Insurance} \head{$+$ \\} \head{Equipment\\} \head{$+$ \\} \head{Truck\\}
 & \head{$=$\\} &
 \head{Bank \\ Loan} \head{$+$ \\} \head{Accounts \\ Payable} \head{$+$ \\} \head{Unearned \\ Revenue}
 & \head{$+$ \\} &
 \head{Share \\ Capital} \head{$+$ \\} \head{Retained \\ Earnings}
  \end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I didn't know `xcolor` had a `table` option. This looks really useful. I prefer this to my answer as I think it will get the alignment right in a wider range of cases.

Answer (score 5):

For example, you might try something along these lines if you took the `tcolorbox` route. This code defines a new command `\mybox` which takes one optional and two mandatory arguments. (This is based on the `tcolorbox` manual's examples.) The optional argument specifies the main colour. The first mandatory argument specifies the title and the second the main body of the box. You can then use a normal `tabular` environment or whatever you prefer to set out the contents of the main part of the box. `\myinterbox` takes exactly one argument which is the symbol you want to use in between two boxes.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{mybox}[2][black]{%
  colback=#1!10!white, colbacktitle=#1!10!white, coltitle=#1!70!black, title={#2}, fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily, center title, center upper, colupper=#1!70!black, fontupper=\bfseries\sffamily, arc=0pt, boxrule=0pt, titlerule=.5mm, leftupper=0pt, rightupper=0pt, bottom=0pt, top=0pt, nobeforeafter}
\newcommand*{\myinterbox}[1]{%
  \tcbox[colback=white, center upper, colupper=black, fontupper=\bfseries\sffamily, arc=0pt, boxrule=0pt, titlerule=0pt, leftupper=0pt, rightupper=0pt, bottom=0pt, top=0pt, nobeforeafter]{\begin{tabular}{c}#1\\#1\\\mbox{ }\\\end{tabular}}}


\begin{document}

\noindent\mybox[green]{ASSETS}{%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{*{9}{c}}
    & + & Accounts & + & Prepaid & + & Equipment & + & Truck\\
   Cash & & Receivable & & Insurance & & & &
  \end{tabular}}
\myinterbox{=}
\mybox[blue]{LIABILITIES}{%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
    Bank & + & Accounts & + & Unearned\\
    Loan & & Payable & & Revenue
  \end{tabular}}
\myinterbox{+}
\mybox[red]{EQUITY}{%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{*{3}{c}}
    Share & + & Retained\\
    Capital & & Earnings
  \end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image: Coloured boxes]

Comment: This looks great although I couldn't get tcolorbox to work, so I accepted the other answer.

Comment: Do you mean my code failed for you? Or something else went wrong?

Comment: Yes, for some reason the tcolorbox.sty wouldn't load, I installed it through MikTex and then manually and for some reason it wouldn't load through Kile. It's just my own problem, I'm sure your code works when tcolorbox works.

Comment: @SamuelReid Oh, I see. Yes, that does sound like one problem which I'm not to blame for! I'm using TeX Live so I'm not much help with MiKTeX but there are questions around about the package manager. Otherwise, I'd open a new question if you can't sort the issue out yourself. I think Harish Kumar's answer is better than mine anyway so I wouldn't worry for this particular case. His will align things correctly in cases where mine will not (or will not without fiddling).